# How do I use the Monte Carlo method to find the uncertainties of a value?

Tags: python, math, physics, montecarlo

I am trying to solve a Physics equation using a Monte Carlo simulation which I know is very long (I just need to use it to learn about it).

I have around 5 values, one is time and I have the random uncertainties (errors) for each of these values. So like mass is (10 +- 0.1)kg, where the error is 0.1 kg

How do I actually find the distribution of measurements if I performed this experiment 5,000 times for example?

I know I could make 2 arrays of errors, and maybe put them in a function. But what am I supposed to do to then? Do I put the errors in the equation and then add the answer to the arrays, and then put the changed array values in the equation and repeat this a thousand times. Or do I actually calculate the real value and add it to the array.

Please can you help me understand this.

## Edit:

The problem I have is basically of a sphere of density ds that is falling by a distance l in time t through a liquid of density dl, this fits in an equation for viscosity and I need to find the distribution of viscosity measurements.

The equation shouldn't matter at, whatever equation I have I should be able to use a method like this to find the distribution of measurements. Weather I'm dropping a ball out a window or whatever.

Comment: Could you please describe in more details the physics problem you are trying to solve (including what is given and what the answer should look like). I don't understand it so far and not sure you can use Monte Carlo method to solve it.

Comment: @SergGr The problem I have is basically of a sphere of density ds that is falling by a distance l in time t through a liquid of density dl, this fits in an equation for viscosity and I need to find the distribution of viscosity measurements.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. The problem you described doesn't seem to fit your original description. The problem looks like something like statistical physics: you have some distribution and some law and you want to find some aggregate distribution. Your original description contains some measurement errors. Yes, specific equation should not matter but the form of that problem: what is given and what is the format of the expected answer does matter. And it is still not clear what kind of a distribution you are calculating. Is it an estimate for a single value or something else?

Comment: Basically I have to calculate the distribution of viscosity values from a formula, each value in the formula I have with its error as well. But I need to calculate how these values change when I simulate the equation 5000 times. All my uncertainties are assumed to be Gaussian distributed. All values are independent from each other. -- I have to do a MonteCarlo simulation to find the distribtuion of these values if this was simulated 5000 times.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Monte Carlo is very straightforward. The following might get you started:

```
import random,statistics,math

#The following function generates a
#random observation of f(x) where
#x is a vector of independent normal variables
#whose means are given by the vector mus
#and whose standard deviations are given by sigmas

def sample(f,mus,sigmas):
    x = (random.gauss(m,s) for m,s in zip(mus,sigmas))
    return f(*x)

#do n times, returning the sample mean and standard deviation:

def monte_carlo(f,mus,sigmas,n):
    samples = [sample(f,mus,sigmas) for _ in range(n)]
    return (statistics.mean(samples), statistics.stdev(samples))

#for testing purposes:

def V(r,h):
    return math.pi*r**2*h

print(monte_carlo(V,(2,4),(0.02, 0.01),1000))
```

With output:

```
(50.2497301631037, 1.0215188736786902)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets try with simple example - you have air gun which shoots balls with mass `m` and velocity `v`. You have to measure kinetic energy

E = m*v<sup>2</sup> / 2

There is distribution of velocity - gaussian with mean value of 10 and std deviation 1.

There is distribution of masses - but we cannot do gaussian, lets assume it is truncated normal, with low limit of 1, so that there is no negative values, with `loc` equal to 5 and scale equal to 3.

So what we will do - sample velocity, sample mass, use them to find kinetic energy, do it multiple times, build energy distribution, get mean value, get std deviation, draw graphs etc

Some simple Python code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import truncnorm

def sampleMass(n, low, high, mu, sigma):
    """
    Sample n mass values from truncated normal
    """
    tn = truncnorm(low, high, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
    return tn.rvs(n)

def sampleVelocity(n, mu, sigma):
    return np.random.normal(loc = mu, scale = sigma, size=n)


mass_low  = 1.
mass_high = 1000.
mass_mu   = 5.
mass_sigma = 3.0

vel_mu    = 10.0
vel_sigma = 1.0

nof_trials = 100000

mass = sampleMass(nof_trials, mass_low, mass_high, mass_mu, mass_sigma) # get samples of mass
vel  = sampleVelocity(nof_trials, vel_mu, vel_sigma) # get samples of velocity

kinenergy = 0.5 * mass * vel*vel # distribution of kinetic energy

print("Mean value and stddev of the final distribution")
print(np.mean(kinenergy))
print(np.std(kinenergy))

print("Min/max values of the final distribution")
print(np.min(kinenergy))
print(np.max(kinenergy))


# print histogram of the distribution
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(kinenergy, 100, density=True, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)

plt.xlabel('Energy')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.title('Kinetic energy distribution')
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

with output like

```
Mean value and stddev of the final distribution
483.8162951263243
118.34049421853899
Min/max values of the final distribution
128.86671038372
1391.400187563612
```

[image]